# download XSD with all imports

Tags: xsd, download, zip

I use gml (3.1.1) XSDs in XSD for my application. I want to download all gml XSDs in version 3.1.1 in for example zip file. In other words: base xsd is [here](http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd) and I want to download this XSD with all imports in zip file or something like zip file. Is there any application which supports that?
I've found this [downloader](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/wellink/archive/2010/09/30/download-all-files-referenced-in-an-xsd-locally.aspx) but it doesn't works for me (I think that this application is not supporting relative paths in imports which occurs in gml.xsd 3.1.1). Any ideas?

Comment: ok, my problem is solved: http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/ :) at this link are zips with xsds, but question is still actual...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[QTAssistant](http://paschidev.com)'s XSR (I am associated with it) has an easy to use function that allows one to automatically import and refactor XSD content as local files from all sorts of sources. In the process it'll update schema location references, etc.

I've made a simple [screen capture](http://paschidev.com/videos/DownloadXSDFiles/DownloadXSDFiles_player.html) of the steps involved in achieving a task like this which should demonstrate its usability.

Comment: Thank you very much man ! your software help me so much !!!

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using SOAP UI.

Follow these steps :

1. Create a project using the WSDL.
2. Choose your interface and open in interface viewer.
3. Navigate to the tab 'WSDL Content'.
4. Use the last icon under the tab 'WSDL Content' : 'Export the entire WSDL and included/imported files to a local directory'.
5. select the folder where you want the XSDs to be exported to.

Note: SOAPUI will remove all relative paths and will save all XSDs to the same folder.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the solution of mschwehl, I made an improved class to achieve the fetch. It suited well with the question. See https://github.com/mfalaize/schema-fetcher

Comment: Works good. However you need to catch all HTTP exceptions and NOT throw them back because this software stops completely if there is one single missing xsd file.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a simple java-main that does the job and change to relative url's

```
package dl;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


public class SchemaPersister {

    private static final String EXPORT_FILESYSTEM_ROOT = "C:/export/xsd";


    // some caching of the http-responses
    private static Map<String,String> _httpContentCache = new HashMap<String,String>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new SchemaPersister().doIt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void doIt() throws Exception {


//      // if you need an inouse-Proxy
//      final String authUser = "xxxxx";
//      final String authPassword = "xxxx"
//
//      System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "xxxxx");
//      System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "xxxx");
//      System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", authUser);
//      System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", authPassword);
//
//      Authenticator.setDefault(
//        new Authenticator() {
//          public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
//            return new PasswordAuthentication(authUser, authPassword.toCharArray());
//          }
//        }
//      );
//      

        Set <SchemaElement> allElements = new HashSet<SchemaElement>() ;

//      URL url = new URL("file:/C:/xauslaender-nachrichten-administration.xsd");
        URL url = new URL("http://www.osci.de/xauslaender141/xauslaender-nachrichten-bamf-abh.xsd");


        allElements.add ( new  SchemaElement(url));


        for (SchemaElement e: allElements) {

            System.out.println("processing " + e);
            e.doAll();
        }


        System.out.println("done!");

    }


    class SchemaElement {

        private URL    _url;
        private String _content;

        public List <SchemaElement> _imports ;
        public List <SchemaElement> _includes ;

        public SchemaElement(URL url) {
            this._url = url;
        }



        public void checkIncludesAndImportsRecursive() throws Exception {

            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(downloadContent() .getBytes("UTF-8"));

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document   doc = builder.parse(in);
            List<Node> includeNodeList = null;
            List<Node> importNodeList  = null;


            includeNodeList = getXpathAttribute(doc,"/*[local-name()='schema']/*[local-name()='include']");
            _includes = new ArrayList <SchemaElement> ();

            for ( Node element: includeNodeList) {

                Node sl = element.getAttributes().getNamedItem("schemaLocation");
                if (sl == null) {
                    System.out.println(_url + " defines one import but no schemaLocation");
                    continue;
                }

                String asStringAttribute = sl.getNodeValue();

                URL url = buildUrl(asStringAttribute,_url);

                SchemaElement tmp = new SchemaElement(url);
                tmp.setSchemaLocation(asStringAttribute);

                tmp.checkIncludesAndImportsRecursive();
                _includes.add(tmp);



            }

            importNodeList =  getXpathAttribute(doc,"/*[local-name()='schema']/*[local-name()='import']");
            _imports = new ArrayList <SchemaElement> ();

            for ( Node element: importNodeList) {

                Node sl = element.getAttributes().getNamedItem("schemaLocation");
                if (sl == null) {
                    System.out.println(_url + " defines one import but no schemaLocation");
                    continue;
                }

                String asStringAttribute = sl.getNodeValue();
                URL url = buildUrl(asStringAttribute,_url);

                SchemaElement tmp = new SchemaElement(url);
                tmp.setSchemaLocation(asStringAttribute);

                tmp.checkIncludesAndImportsRecursive();

                _imports.add(tmp);
            }

            in.close();


        }   


        private String schemaLocation;

        private void setSchemaLocation(String schemaLocation) {
            this.schemaLocation = schemaLocation;

        }

        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159186/how-to-get-parent-url-in-java
        private URL buildUrl(String asStringAttribute, URL parent) throws Exception {

            if (asStringAttribute.startsWith("http")) {
                return new URL(asStringAttribute);
            }

            if (asStringAttribute.startsWith("file")) {
                return new URL(asStringAttribute);
            }

            // relative URL
            URI parentUri = parent.toURI().getPath().endsWith("/") ? parent.toURI().resolve("..") : parent.toURI().resolve(".");
            return new URL(parentUri.toURL().toString() + asStringAttribute );

        }




        public void doAll() throws Exception {


            System.out.println("READ ELEMENTS");
            checkIncludesAndImportsRecursive();

            System.out.println("PRINTING DEPENDENCYS");
            printRecursive(0);

            System.out.println("GENERATE OUTPUT");

            patchAndPersistRecursive(0);

        }




        public void patchAndPersistRecursive(int level) throws Exception {


            File f = new File(EXPORT_FILESYSTEM_ROOT + File.separator + this.getXDSName()  );

            System.out.println("FILENAME: " + f.getAbsolutePath());


            if (_imports.size() > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
                    System.out.print("   ");
                }

                System.out.println("IMPORTS");
                for (SchemaElement kid : _imports) {
                    kid.patchAndPersistRecursive(level+1);
                }

            }

            if (_includes.size() > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
                    System.out.print("   ");
                }

                System.out.println("INCLUDES");
                for (SchemaElement kid : _includes) {
                    kid.patchAndPersistRecursive(level+1);
                }

            }




            String contentTemp = downloadContent();

            for (SchemaElement i : _imports ) {

                if (i.isHTTP()) {
                    contentTemp = contentTemp.replace(
                            "<xs:import schemaLocation=\"" + i.getSchemaLocation() ,        
                            "<xs:import schemaLocation=\"" + i.getXDSName() );
                }

            }


            for (SchemaElement i : _includes ) {

                if (i.isHTTP()) {
                    contentTemp = contentTemp.replace(
                            "<xs:include schemaLocation=\"" + i.getSchemaLocation(),        
                            "<xs:include schemaLocation=\"" + i.getXDSName() );
                }

            }


            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);     
            fos.write(contentTemp.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            fos.close();

            System.out.println("File written: " + f.getAbsolutePath() );




        }



        public void printRecursive(int level) {

            for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
                System.out.print("   ");
            }

            System.out.println(_url.toString());

            if (this._imports.size() > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
                    System.out.print("   ");
                }

                System.out.println("IMPORTS");
                for (SchemaElement kid : this._imports) {
                    kid.printRecursive(level+1);
                }

            }

            if (this._includes.size() > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
                    System.out.print("   ");
                }

                System.out.println("INCLUDES");
                for (SchemaElement kid : this._includes) {
                    kid.printRecursive(level+1);
                }

            }
        }



        String getSchemaLocation() {
            return schemaLocation;
        }



        /**
         * removes html:// and replaces / with _
         * @return
         */

        private String getXDSName() {


            String tmp = schemaLocation;

            // Root on local File-System -- just grap the last part of it
            if (tmp == null) {
                tmp = _url.toString().replaceFirst(".*/([^/?]+).*", "$1");
            }


            if ( isHTTP() ) {

                tmp = tmp.replace("http://", "");
                tmp = tmp.replace("/", "_");

            } else {

                tmp = tmp.replace("/", "_");
                tmp = tmp.replace("\\", "_");

            }

            return tmp;

        }



        private boolean isHTTP() {
            return _url.getProtocol().startsWith("http");
        }




        private String downloadContent() throws Exception {


            if (_content == null) {

                System.out.println("reading content from " + _url.toString());

                if (_httpContentCache.containsKey(_url.toString())) {
                    this._content = _httpContentCache.get(_url.toString());
                    System.out.println("Cache hit! " + _url.toString());
                } else {

                    System.out.println("Download " + _url.toString());
                    Scanner scan =  new Scanner(_url.openStream(), "UTF-8");

                    if (isHTTP()) {
                        this._content = scan.useDelimiter("\\A").next();    
                    } else {
                        this._content = scan.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
                    }

                    scan.close();

                    if (this._content != null) {
                        _httpContentCache.put(_url.toString(), this._content);
                    }

                }


            }

            if (_content == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Content of " + _url.toString() + "is null ");
            }

            return _content;

        }






        private List<Node> getXpathAttribute(Document doc, String path) throws Exception {

            List <Node> returnList = new ArrayList <Node> ();

            XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

            XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();

            {
                XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(path);

                NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET );

                for (int i = 0 ; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                    Node n = nodeList.item(i);

                    returnList.add(n);

                }
            }

            return returnList;

        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {

            if (_url != null) {
                return _url.toString();
            }

            return super.toString();

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  Its a good start but this code has issues.  It doesn't do enough checking to ensure that the same xsd files aren't repeatedly processed.  Also it has a hard time figuring out what to do if two different schemas have the same filename.

Answer (score 2):

I created a python tool to recursively download XSDs with relative paths in `import` tags (eg: `<import schemaLocation="../../../../abc`)

https://github.com/n-a-t-e/xsd_download

After downloading the schema you can use `xmllint` to validate an XML document

Answer (score 0):

I am using org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaResourceManager from the xmlbeans project.  This class is quick and easy to use.

for example:

```
    SchemaResourceManager manager = new SchemaResourceManager(new File(dir));
    manager.process(schemaUris, emptyArray(), false, true, true);
    manager.writeCache();
```

This class has a main method that documents the different options available.