# How does javas URI.resolve work and/or what does it do?

Tags: java, uri

so the question was on how to get a URIs Parent. A working [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10159309/13644859).

I've adapted the code a bit for me:

```
URI testUri = getClass().getResource("/fox/gltf/Fox.gltf").toURI();
System.out.println(testUri);

URI parentURI = testUri.getPath().endsWith("/") ? testUri.resolve("..") : testUri.resolve(".");
System.out.println(parentURI);
```

Which outputs exactly what the Parent URI is `/fox/gltf/`. But why does it work and why do I need to check if the child URI end with a Slash ?

I've tried throwing in three dots but than it creates `/fox/gltf/...` which is not what I expected which is `/fox`

Comment: `.` and `..` have special meanings when used as path segments ("current" and "parent", respectively). See more details here: [What does a dot mean in a URL path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008829/what-does-a-dot-mean-in-a-url-path). However, three dots `...` when used as a path segment have no special meaning. They do not mean "grandparent", if that is what the question was assuming.

Comment: Yeah that was the question. tyvm @andrewjames